# Ubuntu 20.04 - Installation error after restart

Tags: boot, acer, usb-installation

[image: installation error]

```
sd-umoun[46590]: Failed to umount /oldroot: Device or resource busy
...
usb 2-1: device descriptor read/8, error -110
```

Please help.

---

Additional Info:

This is a clean install of Ubuntu and I have completely migrated from Windows 10 to Ubuntu 20.04. However, after installation, my laptop won’t restart or shut down properly without hardpressing the power button. It is just stuck on the black Acer screen as seen in the image above. There is no problem when starting up.

My notebook is:

Acer Aspire E 14
— Intel Core i5
— NVIDIA GeForce 840M
— 8GB DDR3L Memory
— 1000GB HDD

Please help me fix this. Thank you.

Comment: Can you give a bit more information please. Was it a clean installation or an upgrade? If an upgrade, what Ubuntu version was it from? I have had problems in the past if the original installation was too old. Is the error message just, "Installation error or is there more? If an upgrade from an Ubuntu more than a couple of years old, I would recommend backing up the /home partition and doing a clean installation. (I have never lost the data on my /home partition doing this but being somewhat paranoid I still do this whenever I upgrade. Knowing a bit about your hardware setup might also be help

Comment: Please see this link about how to ask good questions: https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: This is a fresh install. I have acer aspire E 14. Intel Core i5-4210U. NVIDIA GeForce 840M. 8GB DDR3 L Memory. 1000GB HDD. 
Sorry I’m new here. Idk how to ask questions since I’m also not good in computer terminologies.

Comment: The thing is. I’ve changed my OS from Windows 10 to Ubunto 5.04. There’s no issue about the deleted files since I want to delete them anyway. The problem is Ubuntu wont shut down or restart properly.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is quite late, but `USB error -110` means that a USB device was drawing too much power and the notebook could not allocate more. If the notebook has an SD card or a USB memory stick that is always plugged in, this could be the source of the problem. Your notebook is probably not getting enough power or, what I see more often is, too many devices are connected and competing for the same limited amount of energy. Flash memory does not operate very well when its starved for power, which would explain why the kernel cannot cleanly unmount the device.